# How can I be sure that I'm using NTP version 4.2.8p1 or equivalent?

Tags: apt, security, ntp

I've recently read about the vulnerabilities within ntp, [here](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/SecurityNotice) which can be closed by installing ntp version 4.2.8p1.

However, I've used `apt-get` to install the latest version of ntp, on an Ubuntu 14.04.2 server, but this is only version 4.2.6p5. I can't find a newer version by browsing the repositories, although I'm fairly new to doing this, so may have missed it. Even Vivid Vervet is showing 4.2.6p5. I'm assuming there's a review process for version changes which is still pending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From usn-2497-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2497-1/) it is stated you need to upgrade to `ntp 1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.04.2`. To me that is the same as your `4.2.6p5` though yours is shortend.

> **Update instructions**
>
> The problem can be corrected by updating your system to the following
>   package version:
>
> Ubuntu 14.10: ntp 1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.10.2
>
> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:     ntp 1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.04.2
>
> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:     ntp 1:4.2.6.p3+dfsg-1ubuntu3.3
>
> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS:     ntp 1:4.2.4p8+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3

---

The [security/updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Upgrades) states you can run `update-manager` from commandline to check if there are pending security updates. If that does nothing you are updated.

---

In Ubuntu, patches are typically backported, and the upstream version (`4.2.6.p5`) remains the same, and the debian revision (`3ubuntu2.14.04.2`) is updated. When in doubt, check the [Ubuntu Security Notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn) and the package changelog.

Comment: Dammit. Slightly faster gun.

Comment: @muru FOR ONCE >:-D