# Is NTPD secure enough for production?

Tags: ntp

I am running Ubuntu Server.

I want to make an application which uses a timestamp. For this I thought it was a good idea to make sure the time is correct on the system. I found this [Time Synchronization with NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/NTP.html).

I can't find anything about the security. Is NTPD secure ? Can I use it in my environment ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a vulnerability found in ntp recently as described [here](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/SecurityNotice), the release number doesn't correspond directly to an Ubuntu ntp package using the same release number, as I found out when I asked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590666/how-can-i-be-sure-that-im-using-ntp-version-4-2-8p1-or-equivalent).

The official Ubuntu security notice that mentions this is [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2497-1/)

Something that I noticed is that the guide you've linked to doesn't mention disabling ntpdate, when you run ntp as a daemon (ntpd). Apparently they don't play nicely together

So the short answer is, yes, so long as you keep your ntp package up to date.